# Speed up numpy calls within Cython

Tags: python, numpy, cython

Iam trying to get some fast cython code but it is surprisingly slow. 
First of all, here is the entire code:

```
import numpy as np
cimport numpy as np
cimport numpy.random
cimport cython

DTYPE = np.float
ctypedef np.int32_t INT32_t


cdef get_random_topleft(double maxDist, double maxAngle, double radius, double boxSize):
    cdef double angle, dist, x, y
    cdef np.ndarray[INT32_t, ndim=1] newTopLeft

    dist = np.random.rand() * maxDist
    angle = np.random.rand() * maxAngle
    newTopLeft = np.empty(2, dtype=np.int32)
    x = dist*np.cos(angle) + radius - boxSize/2
    y = dist*np.sin(angle) + radius - boxSize/2
    newTopLeft[0] = np.int32(np.round(x))
    newTopLeft[1] = np.int32(np.round(y))

    return newTopLeft


def get_random_topLefts(int numBoxes, double boxSize, double radius, double maxAngle, int seed=1337, int maxTries=50):
    cdef np.ndarray[INT32_t, ndim=2] topLefts
    cdef np.ndarray[INT32_t, ndim=1] newTopLeft
    cdef double maxDist
    cdef int outerCounter, counter, x, y, i, j, diffX, diffY, successfullyAdded
    cdef bint validSolutionFound, boxOverlaps

    np.random.seed(seed)
    maxDist = radius - np.sqrt((boxSize/2)**2 + (boxSize/2)**2)
    outerCounter = 0
    validSolutionFound = False

    while not validSolutionFound and outerCounter < maxTries:
        successfullyAdded = 0
        topLefts = np.empty((numBoxes, 2), dtype=np.int32)
        for i in range(numBoxes):
            if i == 0:
                topLefts[0, :] = get_random_topleft(maxDist, maxAngle, radius, boxSize)
                successfullyAdded += 1
            else:
                counter = 0
                while counter < 50:
                    newTopLeft = get_random_topleft(maxDist, maxAngle, radius, boxSize)
                    boxOverlaps = False
                    for j in range(i):
                        diffX = abs(np.float(newTopLeft[0] - np.float(topLefts[j, 0])))
                        diffY = abs(np.float(newTopLeft[1] - np.float(topLefts[j, 1])))

                        if diffX < boxSize and diffY < boxSize:
                            boxOverlaps = True
                            break

                    if boxOverlaps:
                        counter += 1
                    else:
                        topLefts[i, :] = newTopLeft
                        successfullyAdded += 1
                        break

        if successfullyAdded == numBoxes:
            validSolutionFound = True
        else:
            outerCounter += 1

    return validSolutionFound, topLefts
```

According to the html the following lines are very dark yellow and need a lot of c-code. I don't understand why that is... Any hints?

```
dist = np.random.rand() * maxDist
```

(dist and maxDist are declared as doubles)

Simlarly:

```
x = dist*np.cos(angle) + radius - boxSize/2
```

again, dist, angle, radius, boxSize and x are declared as doubles.

Also, simple assignment is slow??

```
topLefts[i, :] = newTopLeft
```

topLefts is declared as np.ndarray[INT32_t, ndim=2] and newTopLeft as np.ndarray[INT32_t, ndim=1]

Any help would be highly appreciated!
Thanks a lot!!

Comment: _According to the html the following lines are very dark yellow and need a lot of c-code._ Isn't it the opposite, yellow lines indicate that there are many Python operations?

Comment: I think those np function calls are still at the python function level. What happens when you rename your cimport as cnp instead? For operating on individual values, you should use functions from libc.math instead.